# Python: calculate values in column only in rows with specific value in other column

Tags: python

I am desperately trying to solve this issue:

I have a csv with information on well core data with different columns, among them one column with IDs and two with X and Y coordinates. I was told now by the data supplier that some of the well cores (= rows) have wrong Y coordinates - the value should be e.g. instead 1400 -1400.

I am now trying to write a script to automatically change all the Y-values in the affected rows (well cores) (by *-1), but nothing has worked:

```
ges = pd.read_csv(r"C:\A....csv") 
bk = [26740001, 26740002, 26740003] # List of IDs that should be changed
for x in bk:
    for line in ges:
        np.where(ges.query('ID== {}'.format(x)), ges.Y=ges.Y*-1, ges['Y'])
```

I have also tried it like this:

```
for line in ges:
    if ges.ID.values == bk:
        ges.Y = ges.Y*-1
    else:
        pass
```

or like this:

```
ges.loc[(ges.ID == bk), 'Y']=*-1
```

or:

```
ges.loc[ges['ID'].isin(bk), ges['Y']] = *-1
```

or:

```
ges.loc[ges['ID'].isin(bk), ges['Y']] = ges['Y']*-1
```

I am very grateful for every help!

edit: 
I am sorry, this is my first post. To make it clearer, my data looks like this:

[image: example]

Now I was informed that the Y-values of ID 2, 3 and 6 are wrong and should be negative values. So my desired output is the following:

```
ID           X               Y            other column       other column
1           3459           1245            information          information
2           4541           -1256           information          information
3           2378           -2353           information          information
4           6947            874            information          information
5           2349           2351            information          information
6           2347            -746           information          information
```

I hope it is clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ids = [26740001, 26740002, 26740003]
for number_id in ids:
    idx = ges['ID'] == number_id
    ges.loc[idx, 'Y'] *= -1
```